# How to use Android Annotations in a library (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-annotations

I have an android project in android studio. One of the modules is a library using android annotations. The other is an application which uses the library. Through much tweaking and googling I've managed to get the library project to generate the "*" files. However, when I run the application it's not including the files, which I can see because it immdiately crashes when it can't find the Application "*" class.

**Library build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.0.1'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

configurations {
    apt
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.hps.mobuyle.core'
        library "true"
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

    // android annotations
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
```

**Application build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.0.1'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

configurations {
    apt
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.hps.mobuyle.core'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    // android annotations
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations" + ":$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile project(':libraryProject')
}
```

**Project settings.gradle**

```
include ':libraryProject'
include ':applicationProject'
```

**Full error output**

```
10-24 13:54:41.890 17670-17670/? E/Zygote: v2
10-24 13:54:41.890 17670-17670/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
10-24 13:54:41.980 17670-17670/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant, PID: 17670
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hps.mobuyle.core.MPApplication_
                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:676)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6289)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hps.mobuyle.core.MPApplication_
                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:220)
                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239)
                                                       at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:211)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1020)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1004)
                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:666)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6289) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hps.mobuyle.core.MPApplication_
                                                       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:209)
                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239) 
                                                       at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:211) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1020) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1004) 
                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:666) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6289) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hps.mobuyle.core.MPApplication_" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
                                                       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285) 
                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:209) 
                                                       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239) 
                                                       at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:211) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1020) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1004) 
                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:666) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6289) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hps.mobuyle.core.MPApplication_" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.1.0_510f17cdc40968bee04a55acc3a74b072e08e08e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slf4j-api-1.7.10_57fc178fc2dace08d430739b21b0d50456c561f2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-logback-android-core-1.1.1-3_79a748caea787f82e8fa3c69f01e9a3885b7ec32-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant/files/instant-run/dex/slice-logback-android-classic-1.1.1-3_c1b46ea01a968
10-24 13:54:42.010 3432-17684/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
10-24 13:54:42.010 3432-17684/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
10-24 13:54:42.010 3432-17684/? E/android.os.Debug: sys.mobilecare.preload = false
```

**Build warnings**

```
Warning:The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[androidManifestFile, resourcePackageName]'
```

Comment: Your project setup seems to be fine (except that you are using `mobuyleCore` in one place and `libraryProject`, but that must be a copy paste error). Can you share the project, so i can have a closer look?

Comment: Yes, that's a copy/paste error.

The project is for an active financial management app on the market so I can't share it. It's being converted from an eclipse project (where everything works as expected).

Comment: Well, there is another thing, which is not a problem, buy maybe you can try it. The `configurations { apt }` block is not needed, you can remove it. Also try to disable multidex and check the result. Also try to update to AndroidAnnotations 4.1.0. What is the error you are exactly getting?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hps.mobuyle.core.MPApplication_

Comment: MPApplication is defined in the library project.

Comment: I updated the original post with the full error message. The build completes successfully but there's a warning tied to apt "Warning:The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[androidManifestFile, resourcePackageName]'"

Comment: That warning is normal. Can you try without multidex and without instant run?

Comment: check fanxu  answer might help you to deal with your issues regarding variants..https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/676#issuecomment-22183943

Comment: Tried without multidex and instant run, same issue. I also tried with fanxu's answer but got the same error.

Comment: @WonderCsabo, I have a paired down version that shows the crash with a minimum of code. How do I share a file through stackoverflow?

Comment: Just open a new repo to GitHub and push it, then link that repo here.

Comment: https://github.com/GingerMcMurray/Android-Annotations-Sample

Comment: Are you sure it was paired down correctly? There is an 'app'  folder under the library project which seems to be at the wrong place.

Comment: That was necessary to get other parts of the project to work (.so files in a library project).

Comment: Well, the current project pushed to GitHub does not make sense, sorry. First of all, the APK will not contain any classes at all from your package. This is because you put the sources into an unconventional folder (lib/app/src/main/java), and not set any of the source sets. Also, what is the point of the library project, if all sources under it? Are you 100% sure that the pushed project is correct?

Comment: The full project contains configurations that change based on the app using the library. It only looks empty because the sample removes everything but what is necessary to recreate the crash.

Comment: The strange project layout was required to get files including imports from .so libraries to compile. It looks like fixing one will break the other and vice versa. Unless there's a way to add those classes to the apk I'll have to go back to the drawing board to find a different way to get the .so libs working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126666/discussion-between-wondercsabo-and-ginger-mcmurray).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your library build.gradle, i found one possible problem. You should always pass strings to the annotation processing options, `true` may not work here, `"true"` should work.

```
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.hps.mobuyle.core'
        library "true"
    }
}
```

I checked out the stripped down [project](https://github.com/GingerMcMurray/Android-Annotations-Sample) on GitHub.

The main problem is that the project has an unconventional layout, however the different project locations are not configured properly. This is why Gradle does not know about the sources at all, and does not include the compiled classes in the APK.

This is what is needed to configure this project layout:

Set the manifest file location:
`manifest.srcFile 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'`

Add Java source folders:
`java.srcDirs += 'app/src/main/java'`

Configure the JNI folders: `jniLibs.srcDirs += 'app/libs'`

Add local dependency jars: `compile fileTree(dir: 'app/libs', include: ['*.jar'])` (note these are under the *app* folder

I also updated the version of the `android-apt` plugin and i also removed the not needed `android.applicationVariants.each` block, which was the way the configure annotation processing before the plugin. Now it is done by the plugin itself.

I also fixed the AA annotation processing parameters in the app project, because it wrongly pointed to the lib project package name:
`resourcePackageName 'com.hps.mobuyle.restaurant'`

The fill set of changes can be found in [this](https://github.com/WonderCsabo/Android-Annotations-Sample/commit/16ba546211b9d1e24dc0c2d2a036bd56951d0618) commit.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I mad that change but still no luck.

Comment: Incredible! Thanks a lot. I was able to reconcile that with the changes neded to get jniLibs working (which caused the wonky structure in the first place) and now at least the most basic version of the app is building and running... Now to move everything else over and hope nothing else melts down. :-)